# PHP throws Exception for a warning

Tags: php, apache, exception

Creating an object from default value is bad, yes, but it usually issues a warning. We try to adapt old and badly-written code, so we got to deal with it.

What i don't get is why it suddenly (and randomly) throws an Exception and stop execution ? I search for a definition a new error handler, or any ini_set, but i can't find one.

Php version is 5.5.31 on apache 2.4.25

Message like this appears every now and then.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' 
    with message 'Creating default object from empty value'
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' 
    with message 'array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given
```

Comment: Are you able to show the offending code and how it is used? Are you able to change it?

Comment: Yes but the problem is not local - it's an array_key_exists on a string, that could be corrected, ok, but the point is on the exception...

Comment: Please set the failing function in the thread.

Comment: The function calls that trigger the error are : while(!array_key_exists('hash', $hash)){ ... some code ... } and $sts[$k]->smst[$k2]->segment[$compteurA]->heureDebut = $k3; (and the thing is not an object, of course)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found it. There was an set_error_handler in a session handler, in the function write.

I was sure that it was not activated, because write() is called when the script terminates.

But i eventually found some script calling a session_write_close(), who triggers the write() function of the session handler, and there you are, warning became exception.

I hope it will be useful for anybody with the same problem. Bottom line: if a warning becomes an exception, then you MUST have a set_error_handler messing things around.